# Hapi JS send file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, mime-types, hapi.js

I have the next task:

one request in my [server](http://spumko.github.io/) wants to get a csv file with statistic. I have JSON structure. With module https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv, I create a csv structure from my json. And the question is: how can I send it to user with correct mime type (text/csv)?

```
var arr = [["date,shop_id,product_id,count"]];
_.each(res, function(date) {
  _.each(date.unknown_products, function(count, product) {
    arr.push([date.date + ',' + id + ',' + product + ',' + count ]);
  });
});

csv()
  .from.array(arr)
  .to(function (data) {
    console.info(data); // => correct csv 
                                //  "date,shop_id,product_id,count"     
                                //  "2013-10-01,1,123,312"
    response += data;
  })
  .on('end', function (count) {
    console.log('Number of lines: ' + count); // => Number of lines: 33878

    //request.reply(new Hapi.response.Obj(response, 'text/csv'));
    request.reply(response);
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I find a solution using `Hapi.response.Stream`:

```
var stream = csv().from.array(arr, {
   columns: ["date", "shop_id", "product_id", "count"]
});


var response = new Hapi.response.Stream(stream);

response.type('text/csv');
request.reply(response);
```

maybe you can tell me the best way to realize it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use: reply(data).type('text/csv')

Comment: How do you define the name of the file sent to the client? reply(data).type('text/csv') works fine but send a "csv" file with no extension, I'd like to generate the name myself.

Answer (score 3):

Might help people looking to respond with a CSV file stream with Hapi V18.

```
const stringify = require('csv-stringify')

const stream = stringify(arrayOfObjects, { header: true })
return h.response(stream)
  .type('text/csv')
  .header('Connection', 'keep-alive')
  .header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  .header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=myfilename.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe at the time of asking this question, the API to return a file might not have been available. However, you can serve static files by using the following methods:

1- The `file` method on the `reply` interface.

```
reply.file('./path/to/file');
```

2- Directly specifying a file handler:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/picture.jpg',
    handler: {
        file: 'picture.jpg'
    }
});
```

Have a look at this Hapi [tutorial](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files) for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use directory :)
After hapi 9.x is no longer integrated with hapi, but you can require and use it.

Check http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files#directory-handler for more information

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
file="path/to/your/csvFile.csv"
return h.file(file,{mode:'attachment',type:'text/csv'})
```